# Comparing JSON object to a model/filter in python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with many objects like the following:

**data**

```json
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "make": "honda",
            "model": "accord",
            "type": "LX",
            "year": 2010,
            "features": [
                { "doors": 4 },
                { "windows": 4 },
                { "avg_horsepower": 200 },
                { "mpg": 30 },
                { "color": "red" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "make": "toyota"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to filter / query these objects against another model / schema, like the following, with support for basic logical operations.

**model**

```json
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "make": "honda",
            "year": {
                "$>=": 2000,
                "$<": 2020
            },
            "features": [
                {
                    "color": {
                        "$or": [
                            "red",
                            "blue"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would hope to be able to something like the following:

**test.py**

```py
import json

def test(data, model):
  do_work_here
  if match:
    return True
  else:
    return False

cars = json.loads(data)
model = json.loads(model)

for car in cars:
  print(test(car, model))
```

expected output:

```
True
False
```

How would you go about filtering a list of objects against another object in a similar format with basic logic? Or is there a pre-built method to accomplish this? I know this is fairly trivial with databases / SQL / mongo, but I have no need of a database for this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [JSONSchema](https://json-schema.org/).  You can see the [keywords like `minimum`, `exclusiveMinimum`, etc](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.2.5) can be used for validation.